# Rust array Iterators modify error, assignment to borrowed `x[_]` occurs here

Tags: rust, iterator

I am learning rust, Run the following code.
I want to change each value of the array

```rust
use rand::Rng;

// fn main() {
//     let mut x: [i32; 30] = [1; 30];
//     for (index, value) in x.iter().enumerate() {
//         // no worker
//         x[index] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..100);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x[_]` occurs here
//         println!("{}",  x[index]);
//     }
// }

fn main() {
    let mut x = [1; 30];
    let enumerate = x.iter().enumerate();
    for index in 0..x.len() {
        // worker!
        x[index] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..100);
        println!("{}",  x[index]);
    }
}
```

I want to know why

Comment: You are looking for [iter_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html).

Comment: Is the `let enumerate = x.iter().enumerate();` really still needed? Because removing that line makes the example work for me. Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f60e2fdbd280380905057a04425e34d6

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because the code is trying to modify an array while it's being used by an iterator. To fix this, you need to use an iterator that allows you to modify the array.

In Rust, there's a distinction between `iter()` and `iter_mut()`. `iter()` returns an iterator that gives you read-only access to the elements of an array, while `iter_mut()` returns an iterator that gives you mutable access to the elements of an array.

So, in your code, instead of using `x.iter().enumerate()`, you can use `x.iter_mut().enumerate()` to get an iterator that lets you modify the elements of `x`:

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut x: [i32; 30] = [1; 30];
    for (_, value) in x.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        *value = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..100);
        println!("{}",  *value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you now no longer need the index, you can even simplify to `for value in x.iter_mut() {`.